# How to stop Drag and Drop bubbling?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, draggable

I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to find a solution. I am using HTML5's native drag and drop features, which are working great, until I drag a card over another card and they're combining. I don't want them to combine but to drop under the next card.

I assume it's something to do with the appendChild or the fact the cards are within the droppable wrapper? But I can't seem to find another way... Any help?

The codepen is here: https://codepen.io/_and_why_/pen/RyVGPG

```
<div class="wrap__global">
    <div class="wrap__col col__ideas" id="target" ondrop="drop_handler(event);" ondragover="dragover_handler(event);">
        <h2 class="col__title">Ideas</h2>
        <div id="card0" class="wrap__card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);">
            <h2>Dmmy Idea</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, libero asperiores! Iusto ut, est, facilis dignissimos assumenda sit neque blanditiis deleniti eum libero facere aspernatur numquam repudiandae quas labore enim!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="card1" class="wrap__card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);">
            <h2>Dmmy Idea 2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium, libero asperiores! Iusto ut, est, facilis dignissimos assumenda sit neque blanditiis deleniti eum libero facere aspernatur numquam repudiandae quas labore enim!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap__col col__prom"  id="target" ondrop="drop_handler(event);" ondragover="dragover_handler(event);">
        <h2 class="col__title">Promising</h2>
        <div id="card2" class="wrap__card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);">
            <h2>Dummy promise</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex necessitatibus nobis quasi odit, harum quis culpa. Ad blanditiis deleniti officia, at ducimus ratione, aliquam, ullam, architecto eum tempora nam nulla!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap__col col__do" id="target" ondrop="drop_handler(event);" ondragover="dragover_handler(event);">
        <h2 class="col__title">Do</h2>
        <div id="card3" class="wrap__card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);">
            <h2>Do dummy idea 1</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi unde non dolor corporis repellendus neque modi? Excepturi soluta placeat, quos aliquam enim, tenetur aspernatur officiis hic, quia, rerum iusto alias!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

const card = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap__card');
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap__col');

function dragstart_handler(e) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
    e.dropEffect = "move";
}

function dragover_handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropogation();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}
function drop_handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes looking, I figured it out. I added the noAllowDrop function to the cards and now you can't drag on top of them.

```
<div id="card2" class="wrap__card" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstart_handler(event);" ondragover="noAllowDrop(event)">
            <h2>Dummy promise</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex necessitatibus nobis quasi odit, harum quis culpa. Ad blanditiis deleniti officia, at ducimus ratione, aliquam, ullam, architecto eum tempora nam nulla!</p>
    </div>


function noAllowDrop(ev) {
    ev.stopPropagation();
}
```